# Proving laws of exponents for natural numbers using Peano's Postulates

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling with this:

Define $P_m :N\to N$ by $P_m (n)$ = nm and $m^n$ as $(P_m)^n (1)$

Now prove $k^{m+n}= k^m k^n$, and $k^{mn} = (k^m)^n$ and $(k^n)(m^n)= (km)^n$
for all $ k,m,n \in N$

Much appreciated! - I can get the first one using induction but the others are allusive...

Answer (score 0):

All three identities are proved via Mathematical Induction.

We first need to prove recursive identities.

Using the above definition for exponents of the natural numbers it is shown 
that $m^0 = 1$ and $m^{S(n)} = m(m^n) $, where S is the successor function
from Peano's postulates.

$m^0 = (P_m)^0(1) = 1N(1)=1$, so $m^0=1$

$m^{S(n)} = (P_m)^{S(n)}(1)= P_m(P_m)^n(1)= P_m(m^n)= m(m^n)$

Let $U$ be the set of natural numbers, for which $k^{m+n}=k^m k^n$ is true.
We use induction on $ n \in N$ for all natural numbers $m$.

$0 \in U,$ as $k^{m+0}= k^m= k^m 1= k^m k^0$

Assume $n \in U$, then $k ^{m+S(n)}= k^{S(m+n)} = k(k^{m+n})= k(k^m k^n)$ = $k(k^n k^m)$ = $(kk^n)k^m $= $k^{S(n)}k^m$

So $ S(n) \in U $ and $U=N$ by PMI

Second identity: Prove $k^{mn} = (k^m)^n $

The proofs of the other two identities are similar. Let me know if you would like them and I'll post them...